# Wordpress - How to set title dynamically based on content?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, title

I try to set custom titles using data from the content. Those are not pages nor posts - plugin (chaturbate) that I'm fixing somehow process urls like /lala-fafa without having any entries in the posts table.

Here is my code

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'chfix_alter_title', 9999);
function chfix_alter_title($title, $id=null)
{
    global $chfix_values;
    return "$chfix_values[Name] $chfix_values[Age]...";
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'chfix_doit', 9999 );
function chfix_doit($content)
{
    global $chfix_names, $chfix_values;


    if (!is_admin())
    {
        foreach($chfix_names as $name)
        {
            // parsing content
            $chfix_values = chfix_get_field($content, $name);
        }
    }
    return $content;

}
```

The problem is that the_title filter is called AFTER the_content filter. I also tried wpseo_title, widget_title with no luck. Is any possibility to make what I want?

Comment: Means  you have to set title page wise?

Comment: I want to fetch some data from the content and use it in the title. Dynamically. Actually, they aren't pages or post, I guess it's done by processing 404 error.

Comment: Can you give me one example, with some content and title, so i can help you?